# Which type of being came first?

Tags: harry-potter

Which came first, muggles or magical beings, squibs or Muggle-borns.
and why are there so few  magical beings?
This is just a matter of curiosity.

Comment: [Wizards originate from Mars, Muggles from mushrooms.](http://web.archive.org/web/20110514102401/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/wotm.cfm)